# raspberrypi: sudo apt-get update isn't working

Tags: raspberry-pi3

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease
Ign:3 https://raspbian.snips.ai/buster stable InRelease
Err:4 https://raspbian.snips.ai/buster stable Release
404 Not Found [IP: 143.204.15.89 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://raspbian.snips.ai/buster stable Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

configuration details.
```

Answer (score -1):

The question is answered here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/732985/force-update-from-unsigned-repository

You can either shut off the security for repo updating or exclude those repos from security checks.

Comment: That solution has nothing to do with OP's question